# Chart pizza não está sendo "fatiado" usando SfChart

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, chart

Fiz esse chart usando Syncfusion Chart,

```
private async void CriaChart()
{
    SfChart chart = new SfChart();
    DataService dataService = new DataService();

    try
    {
        PieSeries pieSeries = new PieSeries()
        {
            ItemsSource = await dataService.GetDataGrid(IdOrcamento),
            XBindingPath = "TotalVenda",
            YBindingPath = "TotalLucro",
            ExplodeIndex = 1,
            ExplodeRadius = 10
        };

        pieSeries.DataMarker = new ChartDataMarker();
        chart.Legend = new ChartLegend();
        chart.Title.Text = "Gráfico da Venda";
        pieSeries.Label = "TotalLucro";
        pieSeries.DataMarker.LabelContent = LabelContent.Percentage;
        chart.Series.Add(pieSeries);

        this.Content = chart;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Meu serviço me entrega isso:

```
{
    "IdOrcamento": 100030087,
    "TotalVenda": 1094,
    "TotalLucro": 273.71
}
```

Acontece, que ao montar o gráfico a fatia referente ao lucro não aparece, conforme screenshot abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso esse [site](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/charttypes#pie-chart) para fazer. Tentei fazer conforme exemplo da Syncfusion.

Comment: mas só tem um valor passado, logo ele representa 100% do todo.. se tiver um parametro para 100% ou se tiver 2 ou mais referencias, talvez ele divida a pizza, nao é?

Comment: tenta algo como 
{
    "IdOrcamento": 100030087,
    "TotalVenda": 1094,
    "TotalLucro": 273.71
},
{
    "IdOrcamento": 100030087,
    "TotalVenda": 700,
    "TotalLucro": 230.71
}

Comment: se sua ideia é exibir totalvenda e a fatia do lucro, tenta lançar como 2 lançamentos, onde valorvenda de um seja o valor real da venda e de outro seja o lucro, provavelmete funcione

Comment: Então, eu passei dois valores  XBindingPath = "TotalVenda",            YBindingPath = "TotalLucro". 1094 representa o total da venda e 273,71 representa a fatia do lucro, numa aritmética simples: **Total -(qtde*custo)** essa é a regra passada pelo cliente, que dá esse valor, num percentual de 25% aproximadamente.

Comment: Parece que ele considera apenas o primeiro valor, pois se eu inverter, vai pegar 100% do lucro.

Comment: @MichelSimões, a idéia é mostrar um gráfico por venda. Tenho uma grid com várias vendas, o cliente escolhe e visualiza no chart. Colocar duas vendas, não seria o caso. Só não entendo porque ele não considera o segundo valor.

Comment: Entao minha suposição está correta sobre vc querer exibir total da venda e o lucro, ele vai comparar entradas de um array, o que voce precisa mesmo é ter os diferentes valores em diferentes chaves, ai sim ele vai cosiderar cada entrada como um dado informativo para montar o chart.

Comment: @MichelSimões, então não vou conseguir montar uma gráfico apenas com uma venda. Não estou entendendo o que você está dizendo. Por venda, eu tenho apenas Total e Lucro.

Comment: Um gráfico deve ter ao menos 2 valores, se nao fica 100% como o seu. Se o seu está com 100% supoe-se que ele pegue apenas 1 valor. Minha sugestão foi apenas voce tratar essa entrega do serviço, ao inves de pegar 1 matriz, com 3 campos, transformar ela em 2 matrizes, podendo cada uma delas conter apenas 1 valor. ex: { "Total": 1094 }, {  "Total": 273.71 } . desta forma ele entenderá que voce tem 2 valores comparativos, lançara a proporção na pizza.

Comment: @MichelSimões, agora ficou mais claro. Vou carregar tudo num array, onde tenho, dois campos, {TotalVenda: 1094}, {TotalLucro: 273,31}, acho que é isso ou não?

Comment: vc precisa comparar os mesmos valores, para poder setar eles no seu código para comparar. mas é isso mesmo. vc vai setar a sua key aqui: 'XBindingPath' entao os valores devem advir da mesma key passada nesta. ex: XBindingPath: "valor" e ai sua array sera {valor: "900"}, {valor:"100"}. isso dará provavelmente uma proporção de 10 e 90%

Comment: o outro valor que voce passou YBindingPath creio que seja para quando usar gráficos em linha, ou 2D

Comment: Então, tá confuso isso. Veja só, o que meu cliente quer é um gráfico por vendas, ok? Que mostre a venda e o lucro, até aí ok. Agora, se coloco duas vendas para comparar, é que não estou entendendo a sua lógica, me desculpe. Porque teria que carregar duas vendas?

Comment: Na documentação do chart, diz, que para chart tipo Pie deverá ser passado dois valores como eu coloquei. Aqui a documentação: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/charttypes#pie-chart

Comment: velho, vc nao vai carregar duas vendas, voce vai carregar 1 venda com os valores de venda e lucro separado em dois retornos. SÒ ISSO. é 1 venda com os valores comparados, mas para serem comparados devem ter o mesmo nome. nao significa que sao vendas diferentes, apenas dados diferentes para comparação. Mas é apenas uma suposição com base em tudo que ja fiz em JS, PHP e JAVA.

Comment: @MichelSimões, entendi. É que ficamos tão dentro da "casinha" que não vemos os arredores dela. Entendo.

Comment: :) boaa!! se der certo da um joinha ;)

Comment: @MichelSimões, a sua idéia estava certa em relação a duas vendas. Fiz diferente um pouco da sua implementação e está ok agora, vou postar o meu, mas se postar algo que me leve a solução marco a sua resposta e não a minha. A minha só daqui a dois dias.

Comment: Parabéns, o importante é resolver! 
só cuidado com a regra de responder as próprias perguntas, algum mod pode te punir... Mas nao vou postar pq nao sei nada da sua linguagem.

Comment: Mas qual o problema de responder as próprias perguntas?

Comment: muita gente fazia assim no começo, lançava uma pergunta e ele mesmo respondia pra ganhar reputação. ta nas regras do grupo algo do tipo

Comment: Achei que quem respondesse a própria pergunta, não ganhava pontos e acho que deveria ser assim, porque eu por exemplo, faço a pergunta, mas não fico aguardando a resposta. Continuo correndo atrás e quando acho antes dos outros, eu respondo. A partir de agora vou responder editando o post. E na maioria das vezes, quando acho e outros respondem, dou sempre a preferência para marcar as outras e não a minha própria.

Comment: que orgulho de vc aspira!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é a minha classe

```
public class DataModelGrid
    {
        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        public List<LiberacaoItensGrid> itensGrid = new List<LiberacaoItensGrid>();
        public List<GeraGrafico> GeraChart { get; set; }
        public double IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        public double TotalVenda { get; set; }
        public double TotalLucro { get; set; }
        public DataModelGrid(double id)
        {
            GetService(id);
            GeraChart = new List<GeraGrafico>();
            GeraChart.Add(new GeraGrafico() { Assunto = "Vendas", Total = TotalVenda });
            GeraChart.Add(new GeraGrafico() { Assunto = "Lucro", Total = TotalLucro });
        }        
        public async void GetService(double id)
        {
            itensGrid = await dataService.GetDataGrid(id);
            foreach (var item in itensGrid)
            {
                this.IdOrcamento = item.IdOrcamento;
                this.TotalVenda = item.TotalVenda;
                this.TotalLucro = item.TotalLucro;
            }
        }
        public class GeraGrafico
        {
            public string Assunto { get; set; }
            public double Total { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Aqui pego os dados do meu serviço:

```
public async Task<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>> GetDataGrid(double id)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);

                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

E a criação do Chart

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Grafico : ContentPage
    {
        SfChart chart = new SfChart();
        DataModelGrid dataModelGrid;
        public double IdOrcamento { get; set; }

        public Grafico(double _idorcamento)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CriaChart(_idorcamento);
        }

        private void CriaChart(double id)
        {
            SfChart chart = new SfChart();
            dataModelGrid = new DataModelGrid(id);

            try
            {
                PieSeries pieSeries = new PieSeries()
                {
                    ItemsSource = dataModelGrid.GeraChart, 
                    XBindingPath = "Assunto",
                    YBindingPath = "Total"
                    //ExplodeIndex = 1,
                    //ExplodeRadius = 10
                };

                pieSeries.DataMarker = new ChartDataMarker();
                chart.Legend = new ChartLegend();
                chart.Title.Text = "Gráfico da Venda";
                pieSeries.Label = "Total";
                pieSeries.DataMarker.LabelContent = LabelContent.Percentage;
                chart.Series.Add(pieSeries);

                this.Content = chart;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```